# How do you decrypt SIP over TLS in Wireshark (Cisco UCM 10.5)

Tags: ssl, sip, wireshark, cisco, cucm

I have a Cisco UCM 10.5 running and would like to know how I can decrypt SIP over TLS traffic between phone endpoints and the UCM.

I haven't been able to find a guide that works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Wireshark to find out the cipher used. One way to find out is to look at the Server Hello message: see the attached image: [image: here]).

If it is not related to Diffie-Hellman (has "DHE" in the cipher suite), then you can decrypt it with server private key by using Wireshark.